# Check variable is not less than zero

Tags: php

I need to Check variable is not less than zero

```
if ( $currentUserLimits >= 0 ) {
        //do something
} elseif($currentUserLimits < $totalPurchaseUnitCount && $currentUserLimits not less then 0) {
        //do something else.
} else {
        //do something else.
}
```

> Clear my question

This is all about offers apply on products and each customer have a purchases limit I have 2 variables and 3 cases.

1. var1 `$currentUserLimits` which will return the current customer limits.
2. var2 `$totalPurchaseUnitCount` which will return the current purchases.

My 3 cases.

1. Case 1: if the `$currentUserLimits still > 0` means the customer still have units in offer. Ex. `$currentUserLimits = 15` and the `$totalPurchaseUnitCount = 10` still the customer has 5 in his `$currentUserLimits`.
2. Case 2: if the customer has half of his $totalPurchaseUnitCount in offer and the order half outside the offer. Ex. `$currentUserLimits = 5` and the `$totalPurchaseUnitCount = 10`.
3. Case 3: if the customer finishes his limits completely so the `$currentUserLimits` is 0 or less then 0.

Sorry making y'all read all this stuff but really the 3 cases confuses me.

how to write `not less than 0`

Comment: `if ($currentUserLimits >= 0)` is the same as "not less than 0". You could also write `if (!($currentUserLimits < 0))`.

Comment: That essentially means that in order to trigger the 2nd clause, you'd need to have already passed the first check. Can you give more detail on this? In the current form, the code itself isn't logically sound.

Comment: 2nd clause is when your are not in( $currentUserLimits >= 0 ) =>  ($currentUserLimits < 0 ), so every thing is less than zero in 2nd clause

Comment: I think that the only thing that will make this condition logicly correct is if you change the order: `if($currentUserLimits < $totalPurchaseUnitCount && $currentUserLimits >= 0) { .. } elseif ( $currentUserLimits >= 0 ) { .. } else { .. }`

Comment: @JimWright please review my question I have edit it to understand my case.

Answer (score 2):

You already did it on the ($currentUserLimits >= 0)

Comment: Exactly! I don't really understand the question

Comment: @RodrigoCordeiro  I edit my question for better understanding my all case.

Comment: @YousefAltaf, you already did on the first  if, because you're statement is like

Is my $currentUserLimits greater then or equal to zero? return something.
 if my $currentUserLimits is lower than zero, then you will arrive into you other if statements, so what you need is to copy the $currentUserLimits >= 0

Answer (score 0):

Check this out.

```
if ( $currentUserLimits >= 0 ) {
        //do something
} elseif(($currentUserLimits < $totalPurchaseUnitCount) && !($currentUserLimits < 0)) {
        //do something else.
} else {
        //do something else.
}
```

Comment: But the first condition will prevent the second one, so what exactly are you suggesting in this answer

Comment: @AlonEitan I edit my question for better understanding my all case.